# How Would I Call Class1 method to Class 2 So I can Print it out on class 2

Tags: c#, class, random, call, static-methods

*I have 2 Class here. One that creates the random number and one that prints out the random number except class 2 cannot retrieve the random number and I'm not sure why, any help?*

```
{
    class Class1
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            int num = random.Next(33, 126);
            Console.WriteLine(num);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
    class Class2
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
                Class1 number = new Class1();
                Console.WriteLine(num);
                Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}




I tried creating an object for class1 in class2 but it didn't change anything.
```

Answer (score 1):

Your project should only run from a single `public static void Main(string[] args)`

You want to create separate methods in a class to call these:

```
public class Program
{
    class Class1
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Class2 obj = new Class2();
            var num = obj.CreateRandomNumber();
            var num2 = obj.CreateRandomNumber();
            Console.WriteLine(num);
            Console.WriteLine(num2);
        }
    }

    class Class2
    {
        private static Random random = new Random();

        public int CreateRandomNumber()
        {
            int num = random.Next(33, 126);
            return num;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And let's say if I wanted to add an additional 2 random numbers how would I implement that?

Comment: Just call the object again.

`var num1 = obj.CreateRandomNumber();`

`var num2 = obj.CreateRandomNumber();`

Comment: But then it creates an instance where the code is unreachable, it shows Unnecessary Assignment. This is when I call the object again.

Comment: Don't create a second object if you're in the same method. Just call the first one again. The number will be different because you're running the code again (Unless you hit a rare occurrence and somehow get's the same random number).

Comment: If I do that it'll return the same number 2 more times because it's the same int value.

Comment: See edit to code. You need to make the Random Object static.